# u-boot flash probing not working(sf probe 0)

Tags: u-boot

I am trying to replace flash memory blocks however, i could not probe any flash:

```
device>sf probe 0
SF: Unsupported flash IDs: manuf ff, jedec ffff, ext_jedec ffff
Failed to initialize SPI flash at 0:0
```

Do you know how to handle this or any possible reasons or workaround?

Thanks.

Comment: In general, this is not a 'good' question.  Based on your other question, I assume that this is on the HI3518 based IP camera you mention.  This type of problem leads me to assume that you broke your hardware as the flash probe is failing and returning junk.

Comment: It is not a camera :                                                                            
Linux version 3.10.100 (ben@DIR-101) (gcc version 4.7.3 (Broadcom Linux 3.6) ) #2 PREEMPT Tue Mar 28 10:18:42 CST 2017  
 CPU: ARMv7 Processor [414fc091  revision 1 (ARMv7), cr=10c53c7d 
 CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT aliasing instruction cache  
 Machine: Cygnus SoC, model: Cygnus (BCM958300K)

Comment: OK, but my main comment still applies.  If sf probe is not seeing what it's supposed to see, and you're talking about un-modified vendor U-Boot, then something happened to your hardware.  If this is your custom U-Boot build, then it's likely not configuring something correctly.

Comment: It is a modified vendor U-Boot. I will try to check hardware in this case.