# How to transfer firmware from device to device using u-boot and linux console?

Tags: linux, u-boot

I have identical devices and I want to copy the firmware of one to another. I have tried the way described here at [Hacking HI3518 based IP camera](https://felipe.astroza.cl/hacking-hi3518-based-ip-camera/) that is copying mtd partitions and storing them to other device using sf commands. However, I failed at probing stage ([another problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46585542/u-boot-flash-probing-not-workingsf-probe-0)). So, I am looking for another way.

Do you know how to transfer firmware from device to device using u-boot and linux console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Check mtd partions: `cat /proc/mtd`  (linux device)

  ```
  mtd0: 00100000 00020000 "boot1"
  mtd1: 00100000 00020000 "m0patch"
  mtd2: 00100000 00020000 "dtb"
  mtd3: 00200000 00020000 "config"
  mtd4: 00100000 00020000 "info"
  mtd5: 00200000 00020000 "u-boot1"
  mtd6: 00200000 00020000 "u-boot2"
  mtd7: 00800000 00020000 "kernel1"
  mtd8: 00800000 00020000 "kernel2"
  mtd9: 01e00000 00020000 "initrd"
  mtd10: 3c600000 00020000 "rootfs"
  ```
- Copy the mtd partion: `dd if=/dev/mtdblock9 of=/tmp/mtdblock9 bs=65536` (linux device)
- Copy the mtd from device to host using whatever channel avaliable (I use z-modem) : `lsz /tmp/mtdblock9`
- Delete the mtd partion from Nand: `nand erase initrd` (u-boot of other device)
- Delete the mtd partion from mtdparts `mtdparts del initrd`(u-boot of other device)
- Get the mtd image from host to other device (I use `kermit` and `loadb`): gives the address and size which is used in the next command. (Lets say they are 0x00000001 and 0x4000 respectively)
- Write to nand this copied image: `nand write <memory address> <offset> <size>` (0x1e00000 is given in the first command as offset)

  ```
   nand write 0x00000001  0x1e00000  0x4000

  NAND write: device 0 offset 0x01e00000  , size 0x4000
  16384 bytes written: OK
  ```

Comment: i have used u-boot and transferred firmware from one device to another.

Comment: Your first two bullet point look more like Linux shell commands than U-Boot commands to me.  You only use U-Boot to perform the receiving of the image and the writing.

Comment: Ok, i have changed the question

Comment: Okay, but I didn't do the downvoting.

Comment: oh, it is not a problem. In fact, i do not care about votes, i care about information. however, most of the time i do not get any. Maybe i am bad at asking them. Anyway, thank you.